# How to use IF statement inside WITH?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, select, with-statement

Wasn't able to find a proper example of this (or maybe I am simply looking in wrong direction).

Depending on incoming parameter value I need to change `WHERE` condition for `SELECT`.

For example, I got parameter `@bookType` with value 'All' and I need to make something like this:

```
IF @bookType = 'All'
  SELECT * FROM tBooks
  WHERE BookType != 'Template' AND BookGroup='Library'
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM tBooks
  WHERE BookType = @bookType AND BookStatus=@bookStatus
```

Seems simple, but I need this IF inside WITH:

```
WITH Books AS (
  IF...
  ...
), bookIds AS (
  ...
  ...
)
```

And this is not working because I am starting to receive `'Incorrect syntax near IF'`. What exactly I am doing wrong? Or maybe it is possible to hide this `IF` inside `WHERE` statement (change where depending on parameter value)?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Updated tags (mssql, well, tags changes it to sql server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;
WITH Books AS (

     SELECT * FROM tBooks
        WHERE
            (@BookType = 'All'  AND BookType != 'Template' AND BookGroup='Library')
            OR
            (@BookType <> 'All' AND BookType = @bookType AND BookStatus=@bookStatus)

)
```

Comment: Oh... didn't even thinked about this variant... will try it

Comment: Yep... that done the trick. Now i'm felling very stupid for not even thinking about extending WHERE statement...